# How to create computed column with conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, calculated-columns

I have a table containing domain name data & need to add a persisted calculated column based on the domain name “extension” where the domain name = mydomain.com, yourdomain.net, anydomain.org, etc. & the “extension” is .com, .net & .org respectively.  Each domain extension has its own annual renewal cost ($9.17, 8.21, 8.90).

I need the calculated column for each row to represent the annual renewal price of the extension of the domain name:
I have a table containing domain name data & need to add a persisted calculated column based on the domain name “extension” where the domain name = mydomain.com, yourdomain.net, anydomain.org, etc. & the “extension” is .com, .net & .org respectively.  Each domain extension has its own annual renewal cost ($9.17, 8.21, 8.90) respectively.

I need the calculated column for each row to represent the annual renewal price of the extension of the domain name:

There are many other extensions but I use these 3 as an example.  How can this be defined for the table column?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is how you create a computed column that does this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ADD bar AS CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2),
  CASE extension 
    WHEN '.com' THEN 9.17
    WHEN '.net' THEN 8.21
    WHEN '.org' THEN 8.90 
    -- may want an ELSE condition for a fallback
  END);
```

However, why on earth do you want this as a computed column? This should be normalized, you should have a table with renewal rates for each TLD and join to get those values when you need them. Especially if you have a lot more...